# Julia - SymPy creating function

Tags: function, julia, sympy

I'm trying to create a function in the for statement. But it didn't work.

Ex:

```
using SymPy
list=[1,1,-1]
a(x)=2^x
b(x)=3^x
c(x)=4^x
x = symbols("x")

for i=1:length(list) 
   if list[i]==1
      a(x)=a(x)*b(x)
   elseif list[i]==-1         
      a(x)=a(x)*c(x)
   end
end
```

That is to say, I would like to yield,

```
a(x)=2^x*3^x*3^x*4^x
```

However, it only returned the original function.

```
a(x)=2^x
```

I am not sure is it functional or not. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a scoping issue, check the docs here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/

The `for` loop introduces its own scope, so the global `a(x)` that you declare outside the loop isn't affected by what's happening in your loop.

You can either wrap everything you do in a function:

```
function main()
    list = [1, 1, -1]
    ...
    return a(x)
end
```

or annotate the `a(x)` in your loop as `global`. Generally global variables are bad for performance and best avoided in Julia, so you should think about how you can structure your code into functions.

(FWIW I get a `StackOverflowError` for both of the solutions I mentioned here, but that's probably an issue with how you're using SymPy which I know nothing about unfortunately!)